# jQuery plugin methods return object not value

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, methods, jquery-plugins

This is my plugin example:

```
(function($) {
  var YourPlugin = function(element, option) {
    var defaults = {

    };

    this.option = $.extend({}, defaults, option);
    this.$element = $(element);
  };

  YourPlugin.prototype = {
    show: function() {
        return 'Method value';
    }
  };

  $.fn.yourPlugin = function(option) {
    var arg = arguments,
        options = typeof option == 'object' && option;
    return this.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this),
          data = $this.data('yourPlugin');

      if (!data) $this.data('yourPlugin', (data = new YourPlugin(this, options)));
      if (typeof option === 'string') {
        if (arg.length > 1) {
          data[option].apply(data, Array.prototype.slice.call(arg, 1));
        } else {
          data[option]();
        }
      }
    });
  };
}(jQuery));
```

When i call the plugin method 'show' like this:

```
console.log( $( '#header' ).yourPlugin('show') );
```

It's print in the console the element selector object and not the return result of the method function.

How can solve this?

Comment: `$.fn.yourPlugin` is returning `this` so the plugin is chainable. Calling your internal methods doesn't change that return

Comment: @charlietfl Yes i can understand this but i still can't solve the problem please if you have any solution tell me i till trying to solve this problem for more than 2 days :(

Comment: @charlietfl Hmmm okay i understand you but still cant know what's the best solution.

Comment: Don't know enough about what all the features of this plugin need to be or how it needs to be used

Comment: @charlietfl It's very simple I have two plugins and with the second plugin, I need to get a value of a method from the first plugin that' only.